# How to take rows with continous time for more than 3 three rows python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have one data frame i want to get rows when time is continuous for three rows and delete other rows.

```
df_input:

Value         time 
8970    2020-11-20 15:40:00
7602    2020-11-20 15:50:00
7603    2020-11-20 16:00:00
7604    2020-11-20 16:10:00
7757    2020-11-29 06:30:00
7758    2020-11-29 06:40:00
7877    2020-12-02 01:00:00
11179   2021-01-06 23:50:00
11230   2021-01-07 08:20:00
11283   2021-01-07 17:30:00 

df_out:

8970    2020-11-20 15:40:00
7602    2020-11-20 15:50:00
7603    2020-11-20 16:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

by

```
df['timeDiff'] = df['time'].diff()
```

you will get

```
df_input 
Value         time 
8970    2020-11-20 15:40:00
7602    2020-11-20 15:50:00
7603    2020-11-20 16:00:00
7604    2020-11-20 16:10:00
7757    2020-11-20 18:30:00
7758    2020-11-20 20:30:00
```

into :

```
df_output 
Value         timeDiff 
8970    Na
7602    00:10:00
7603    00:10:00
7604    00:10:00
7757    02:20:00
7758    02:00:00
```

then you can group them as you need to determine continues. I guess this will help you to solve the problem.